# Change date format using VBA Code

Tags: vba

I have this code to show the date in the following format like (Date: March 22, 2015) but it shows it as (Date: 3/22/2015) so please assist.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim dtmTest As Date
dtmTest = DateValue(Now)
Range("A1") = Format(dtmTest, "mmmm dd, yyyy")
Range("A1") = "Date : " & dtmTest
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the cell formatting to text to obtain the desired effect.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'Sets cell formatting to string
Range("A4").NumberFormat = "@"
'fills range with formatted date
Range("A4").Value = Format(Now, "mmm, dd yyyy")
End Sub
```

Comment: At which point, it is easier to assign the date format to the cell in the first place and then just set it to `Now`. At which point you don't need a macro, only the format on the cell and the formula, `=NOW()`.

Comment: Many thanks Guys, it works as I wished. really appropriate it.

Comment: @NabilAmer, Gserg's comment says a method that uses no code. I think it's pretty good if you don't want to use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted works, but your original code was almost correct.  You reformatted the date with the format function, but then overwrote it with the dtmtest variable.  Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim dtmTest As Date
dtmTest = DateValue(Now)
Range("A1") = "Date : " & Format(dtmTest, "mmmm dd, yyyy")
End Sub
```